Why is Pdb going into interactive shell code?
I want to jump to download_url function to see its implementation and skip seeing all the stuff in between, how to achieve that? I tried using s and n commands, but it doesn't take you to download_url function. Is there anyway to jump to next called function in PDB?
enter image description here

You should have all sources installed on your virtual environment, no need to use a debugger. Or I miss the meaning of the question? (Some IDE allows you to jump directly in such code, e.g. PyCharm). With sources you have inline documentation, comments, etc. which help to understand the code.

@GiacomoCatenazzi I am using a Kaggle Notebook, for now I am limited to kaggle for this particular piece of code. And yes, I agree on the part about installing all sources on the virtual environment.
